# Zabbix server 2.2.1 again crash

Tags: zabbix

Yesterday my zabbix server ver 2.2.21 crash twice. I attach log files.

http://speedy.sh/hhjjt/log-1.txt
http://speedy.sh/ddTTw/log-2.txt

Zabbix server is working on the following machine:

```
 CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5660 @ 2.80GHz
 CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5660 @ 2.80GHz
 CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5660 @ 2.80GHz
 CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5660 @ 2.80GHz
 HDD: 682G
 RAM: 9.65162 G
```

On the same machine I have all components of zabbix (front-end, server, db). To be sure that zabbix server is always running, I added the following script to crontab

```
 #!/bin/bash

 SHELL=/bin/bash
 PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

 echo $(date +%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M)

 service=zabbix_server

 if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
 then
 echo "$service is running!!!"
 echo " "
 else
 echo "Zabbix Server is not running on $HOSTNAME!!!" > /tmp/mail_zabbix_server
 mail -s "Zabbix server is down on !!!" some_email@zxy.com < /tmp/mail_zabbix_server
 /etc/init.d/zabbix-server start
 rm -rf /tmp/mail_zabbix_server
 fi.
```

Anybody have some idea why my zabbix crash?

Regards
Mick

Comment: What Linux distro you use? Did you install Zabbix from the OS repositories or did you compile it yourself?

Comment: CENTOS 6.4x64 & zabbix are install from repo

Comment: OK, truly shouldn't crash unless you have some very exotic Zabbix 3rd party plugins installed. Is the server otherwise stable? A some kind of hardware fault is what I suspect.

Comment: Can you provide the _actual_ logs, or links to them, rather than links to a very questionable web site? Try pastebin.com

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HQRDYtDR

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RFMt8Ea1

Answer (score 1):

This is probably bug https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7521 .

1) upgrade Zabbix
2) increase ValueCacheSize parameter in the server configuration file as the logfile suggests